# Getting large thumbnail photos from Instagram is no longer working with "replace"

Tags: php, facebook, instagram, instagram-api

For long time I use this "replace function" to get the thumbnails by Instagram API, it worked well but now they changed somethings and I no longer to use bigger thumbnails by this way.

```
src="<?= str_replace('s150x150/', 's320x320/', $post->images->thumbnail->url) ?>">
```

By default thumbnail, it works well.
    https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/94387bd7b8a247f3f4039f8789772142/5AEE2A9E/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/26335890_2247807142112483_5882778660510892032_n.jpg

But replaced thumbnail size to bigger, it appears a msg: Invalid URL signature.

https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/vp/94387bd7b8a247f3f4039f8789772142/5AEE2A9E/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/26335890_2247807142112483_5882778660510892032_n.jpg

Anyone can help to get bigger thumbnail of Instagram. They changed API and I feel so tired with Facebook, they have made many changes since sync with FB and everytime like this, the developers have to update with no instructions.

Comment: Looks like a part of the new URL is hashed to prevent non-registered bots to crawl for bigger pictures. Have you tried using their API instead? I think, a call to `https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN` should give you what you need - a profile picture.

Comment: Hi Alex Karshin. the IG user gave permission with my app. I can make sure it is running through API. like this: `$result = fetchData("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{$userid}/media/recent/?access_token={$accessToken}&count={$display}");`

Comment: Okay, two things: First. I was able to manually get a 320x320 picture of some other completely unrelated person on IG. This probably narrows your problem to the user you're getting picture from. Second. An API call returns a little bit different profile_picture and you should use it. Can't you?

Comment: Can you suggest me the solution? Thank you so much. I feel so tired with Instagram because they have updated API frequently but they did not make the easy way to developers. By this, it affects to a lot of users.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't, sorry. I do not work with IG at all, I was just trying to point you in the right direction, hoping you find a solution yourself...

Comment: However, thank you so much for your suggestion.

Answer (score 8):

You can try with this trick

```
src="<?= str_replace('s150x150/', 's320x320/', str_replace('vp/', '', $post->images->thumbnail->url)) ?>">
```

or

```
src="<?= str_replace('s150x150/', 's640x640/', str_replace('vp/', '', $post->images->thumbnail->url)) ?>">
```

You have to replace (delete) also "vp/" on url, and works again.
It's a really bad solution, but it's the only that i've found.

Comment: Just a note, I don't think even this works anymore, at least not at the same time as upsizing the thumbnail.

Answer (score 6):

Copy the **link** of the profile pic after the "/s150x150/**xxxxxxxx......jpg**" to the end of this:

"https://instagram.flju2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/e890a9f0b7b40abe5667b06d0fa750e5/"

like: https://instagram.flju2-1.fna.fbcdn.net/vp/e890a9f0b7b40abe5667b06d0fa750e5/**xxxxxxxx......jpg**

Works right now.

Answer (score 1):

A solution would be very nice!
I have also done it like you the last few month.

I think one of the solutions is to use non-squared fotos from instagram (you get with "standard_resolution") and set it as a background-image and do the "square" via css and display cover…

This is my personal solution at the moment…

Answer (score 0):

i opened instagram on google chrome selected the desired post, right-clicked to "save as". after opening the saved html doc. in chrome i right-clicked again to veiw page source. i scrolled down to line 217 of the page source and one of the links there gave me the picture i wanted. not sure that it is the same thing as before but it let me download the picture of the post in a .jpg format. hope this helps